# geom_line not plotting when tooltip argument set in ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I am trying to use plotly for interactive visuals in my shiny app. However, I am running into a problem when trying to add a custom tooltip to the graph. If i set the `tooltip` argument in `ggplotly()` then my `geom_line()` is ignored in my output but the tooltip works.

Here is a MRE:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(tidyquant) #only using the palette_dark() function
library(magrittr)

graph <- data %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, result, text = paste0("Site: ", site, "\n", 
                                     "Quarter: ", quarter, "\n", 
                                     "Year: ", year, "\n", 
                                     "Result: ", result))) +
  facet_wrap(~site) +
  geom_point(color = palette_dark()[1]) +
  geom_line(color = palette_dark()[1]) +
  theme_bw() 

 ggplotly(graph, 
          tooltip = "text")
```

This gives me this:
[image]

If I move the `data =`  and `aes()` calls from the `ggplot` call to the individual `geom`s then The lines still aren't shown:

```
graph <- ggplot() +
  facet_wrap(~site) +
  geom_point(data = data, 
             aes(date, result, 
                 text = paste0("Site: ", site, "\n", 
                               "Quarter: ", quarter, "\n",
                               "Year: ", year, "\n", 
                               "Result: ", result)),
             color = palette_dark()[1]) +
  geom_line(data = data, 
            aes(date, result, 
                text = paste0("Site: ", site, "\n", 
                              "Quarter: ", quarter, "\n",
                              "Year: ", year, "\n", 
                              "Result: ", result)),
            color = palette_dark()[1]) +
   theme_bw() 

ggplotly(graph, 
     tooltip = "text")
```

This gives me the same output with the tooltips still working. However, now I receive two warnings:

> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: text
>
> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: text

If I remove the `text=` argument from just the `geom_line()` function then the lines are plotted but the tooltip no longer works:

[image]

**Question:**

How do I get the custom tooltip to work while still plotting my `geom_line()`?

**My data:**

```
data <- structure(list(site = c("Site 1", "Site 1", "Site 1", "Site 1", 
                                    "Site 2", "Site 2", "Site 2", "Site 2", 
                                    "Site 3", "Site 3", "Site 3", "Site 3", 
                                    "Site 4", "Site 4", "Site 4", "Site 4", 
                                    "Site 5", "Site 5", "Site 5", "Site 5"), 
                           parameter = c("Testing Parameter", "Testing Parameter",
                                         "Testing Parameter", "Testing Parameter", 
                                         "Testing Parameter", "Testing Parameter", 
                                         "Testing Parameter", "Testing Parameter", 
                                         "Testing Parameter", "Testing Parameter", 
                                         "Testing Parameter", "Testing Parameter", 
                                         "Testing Parameter", "Testing Parameter",
                                         "Testing Parameter",  "Testing Parameter", 
                                         "Testing Parameter", "Testing Parameter"),
                           year = c(2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
                                    2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
                                    2016, 2017, 2017, 2017), 
                           quarter = c(4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
                                       3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L), 
                           result = c(22.87, 31.78, 54.76, 44.3, 27.78, 34.04, 53.27, 
                                      46.83, 19.83, 34.05, 31.18, 35.7,  24.11, 33.57, 
                                      47.5, 40.53, 29.4, 34.6, 53.18, 46.16), 
                           count = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                     3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
                           date = structure(c(17075, 17167, 17257, 17348, 17075, 
                                              17167, 17257, 17348, 17075, 17167, 
                                              17257, 17348, 17075, 17167,  17257, 
                                              17348, 17075, 17167, 17257, 17348), 
                                            class = "Date")), 
                      class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                      row.names = c(NA, -20L), 
                      .Names = c("site", "parameter", "year", "quarter", "result", 
                                 "count", "date"))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the lines weren't showing up because ggplot didn't know which points to connect together. I tried to plot the first `graph` (without converting to plotly object using `ggplotly`), & got the following warning:

```
> graph
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the
group aesthetic?
```

Adding `group = site` to first set of code worked for me:

```
library(ggplot2); library(dplyr)

graph <- data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = result, 
             text = paste0("Site: ", site, "\n", 
                           "Quarter: ", quarter, "\n", 
                           "Year: ", year, "\n", 
                           "Result: ", result),
             group = site)) +
  facet_wrap(~site) +
  geom_point() + # default palette since I don't have tidyquant
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw()

plotly::ggplotly(graph, tooltip = "text")
```

[image: plotly]

Comment: That does the trick! I would have expected the `facet_wrap` call to handle that internally, but now I know! Thanks!

Comment: In more complex charts, you may want multiple lines within each facet, so it's best that they are handled separately. :)

Comment: @Z.Lin do you know what do to in case you do a `facet_wrap` by 2 variables?